# knockout checkbox toggle css classes and toggle checked upon click

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, checked

```
<div data-bind="css: { highlighted: highlight }, click: toggleHighlight">
  random string
</div>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="css: { 'checked': dimitri, 'unchecked': !dimitri() }, click: toggledimitri, checked: dimitri"> 

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.dimitri = ko.observable(false);
  self.toggledimitri = function() { self.dimitri(!self.dimitri()) };
  self.highlight = ko.observable(true);   
  self.toggleHighlight = function () { self.highlight(!self.highlight()) };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
var vm = ko.dataFor(document.body);
```

What basically I'm after is the toggling of css classes {checked and unchecked} whilst also checking and unchecking the checkbox using knockout checked: css: and click: . Any ideas which bit I'm not doing right? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDypD/51/)

Comment: The `checked` binding does not need an additional `click` binding to gain toggle functionality. Remove the `click` binding from your checkbox and check out what happens.

Comment: firstly thanks for helping and yes it got me a step closer, but although I tried that already I reverted back, since that prevents the unchecked class from being assigned when knockout observable is false. I need a class to be assigned when element is unchecked also.

Comment: You need to use `!dimitri()` in the `unchecked` class binding. `!dimitri` can't unwrap the observable automatically. So: `data-bind="css: { 'checked': dimitri, 'unchecked': !dimitri() }, checked: dimitri"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `css` binding, you can try using the `attr` binding and bind directly to the `class` attribute. You can use a `ko.computed` method to return the appropriate CSS class name. Also, you don't need the `click` event as user3297291 stated. The checkbox would look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { 'class': checkedClass }, checked: dimitri">
```

And the `ko.computed` method would look like this:

```
this.checkedClass = ko.computed(function() {
  return this.dimitri() ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
}, this);
```

Here is a link to the updated fiddle which demonstrates this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KDypD/56/

Comment: thanks mate your different approach is also very appealing and important to have it in mind

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the checked and click will effectively negate each other. The checked binding will automatically toggles while the click manually toggles once more. Removing the click fixes the issue.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="css: { 'checked': dimitri, 'unchecked': !dimitri() }, checked: dimitri">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDypD/55/

Comment: firstly thanks for helping and yes it got me a step closer, but although I tried that already I reverted back, since that prevents the unchecked class from being assigned when knockout observable is false. I need a class to be assigned when element is unchecked also.

Comment: @JoeBorg You can't use `!dimitri` because `dimitri` is an observable. You have to get its contents if you're making any expression from an observable: `unchecked: !dimitri()`
Note that the answer has that.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks man for clarifying further, such simple syntax change and makes all the difference, I think I might have found something similar on the net before posting the question here, and for some reason either I waas trying too often on the fiddle and it didnt update code changes, I recall that the solution similar to yours didnt work out. but now that I slowly tried yours its working fine :)